# Biblatex \textcite using a superscript reference number

Tags: biblatex, citing

I would like to typeset the citation number produced by `\textcite` as a superscript number, rather than enclosed by brackets, in line with the rest of my document. Is it possible to typeset "Author ^1" when `autocite` is set to `superscript` rather than the default "Author 1"?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,autocite = superscript]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{ABib.bib}
@article {article1,
 AUTHOR = {Author, A. N.},
 TITLE = {A sample paper},
 JOURNAL = {Sample journal},
 VOLUME = {1},
 YEAR = {2013},
 NUMBER = {1},
 PAGES = {1--2}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{ABib.bib}

\begin{document}
Someone saw something \autocite{article1}.

\textcite{article1} saw something.
\end{document}
```

[image: The problem: references are different]

Comment: You want ``\autocite``, ``\textcite`` both to give superscripts for references ? You do not want to use ``\supercite`` (which prints superscripted references) ?

Comment: @ach: I would like the citation number that is at the end of `\textcite` to be superscript (since the superscript option is chosen for biblatex). The MWE produces a "^1" for the `\autocite` but `\textcite` produces an inline style reference number "[1]" after the author name and year. I would have expected `\textcite` to typeset the reference number using the same style as the other citations.

Comment: I added an image which shows the issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this will do the job: it's largely a matter of copying the definitions pertinent to `\supercite` into the commands that define `\textcite`. Please note that I have "hardwired" this, in other words it will not adapt automatically to changes in "autocite", so if you stopped using "autocite=superscript" you would need to delete the redefinitions too.

Also, as with other superscript references, pre- and postnotes are not printed, but a warning is written to the log.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,autocite = superscript]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{ABib.bib}
@article {article1,
 AUTHOR = {Author, A. N.},
 TITLE = {A sample paper},
 JOURNAL = {Sample journal},
 VOLUME = {1},
 YEAR = {2013},
 NUMBER = {1},
 PAGES = {1--2}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{ABib.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\mkbibsuperscript{\supercitedelim}}
    {\cbx@tempa
     \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
       {\printnames{labelname}}}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
    {}
    {}%
  \mkbibsuperscript{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
  \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
  \gdef\cbx@tempa{\addspace\multicitedelim}}%

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\let\cbx@tempa=\empty
   \undef\cbx@lasthash
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Someone saw something \autocite{article1}.

\textcite{article1} saw something.
\end{document}
```

Producing:

[image]

Comment: It is surprising to me that this is not the default behaviour for this set of options. The code you provided does the job I need though so thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't using \let\textcite=\autocite achieve the same result?

Comment: Is there a way to give parencite the same effect?

Comment: Yields `Package biblatex: Bibliography macro 'cite' undefined.` for me.

Answer (score 7):

Another easier possibility if using the natbib and biber options in the biblatex package is this:

```
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=chem-acs,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=true,
    autocite=superscript
]{biblatex}
\newcommand{\authorcite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}\,\supercite{#1}}


\authorcite{CitationKey}
```

will result in 
Author1 and Author^1

Comment: Note that the method of defining citation commands by putting two or more `\cite*` commands together into a `\newcommand` has several shortcomings. It does not support pre- or postnotes (though that could be remedied, I suppose), and it does not support citation of several works at the same time properly. So generally, a `\DeclareCiteCommand` is to be preferred.

Comment: @moewe Still, it's much simpler than the accepted solution, if you are looking for a fast hack. I'm giving it a like. Haven't seen any problems in practice.

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś I'm well aware that people gravitate towards shorter (and simpler or easier-to-understand) solutions and that the two answers here are a prime example of this. For most uses people will probably not happen upon or care about the drawbacks of the specific solution here. Still it is important to me to have warned people about that, especially since the general approach of putting together several `\cite...` commands can be seen more often and always has structurally similar shortcoming that can manifest itself in more or less problematic ways. ...

Comment: ... What you do with my advice is completely up to you.