# Biblatex \textcite multiple refs of the same author with superscript reference number

Tags: biblatex, citing, multiple-citations

This question is related to [Biblatex-nature \textcite with superscript reference number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162309/biblatex-nature-textcite-with-superscript-reference-number), which shows how to make \textcite use superscript number.

But it does not work when I cite multiple references of the same author.

Here is a MWE (the result is something like Author<sup>1</sup>-3)

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{ABib.bib}
@article {a1,
 AUTHOR = {Author},
 TITLE = {A sample paper},
 JOURNAL = {Sample journal},
 VOLUME = {1},
 YEAR = {2013},
 NUMBER = {1},
 PAGES = {1--2}}
@misc{a2,
 AUTHOR = {Author},
 TITLE = {A sample paper},
 YEAR = {2013}}
@misc{a3,
 AUTHOR = {Author},
 TITLE = {A sample paper},
 YEAR = {2013}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{ABib.bib}

%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
     \ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\bibclosebracket\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
       {}%
     \iffirstcitekey
       {}
       {\textcitedelim}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
     \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
       {\printnames{labelname}}%
     \addspace
     \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
       {}%
     \mkbibsuperscript{\usebibmacro{cite:comp}}%
     \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
     \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\textcite{a1,a2,a3}
\end{document}
```

p.s. The original question was asked long time ago, and I am too new to have enough reputation to comment there, so I ask this new question here.