# Is there any bibLaTeX style that has superscript numbers?

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

I'm using the [Overleaf documentation](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Biblatex_citation_styles) to produce a bibliography with in-text citations, using bibLaTeX (compiler is XeLaTeX, document class is article). I've tried all of the citation styles on the overleaf webpage, and none produce superscript in-text citations (i.e. numbers as superscripts). The closest I can get is numbers in square parentheses.

Is there no citation style that has superscript numbers? Or does this indicate that something else is going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Welcome! Is this previous question perhaps related to what you want? [Biblatex \textcite using a superscript reference number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114833)

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful - not the answer itself, but the addition of "autocite=superscript" to the Biblatex preamble, and then the use of \autocite rather than \cite in the text, as stated in the question. For the record, it does surprise me that there's no bibliography style for which the default \cite command is superscripted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard numeric styles implement the command `\supercite` for superscript citations (without brackets by default; they look pretty much like footnote numbers, but very much aren't).

Because it is cumbersome to have to switch from e.g. `\parencite` to `\supercite` if you change citation styles, `biblatex` offers the high-level `\autocite` command, whose exact behaviour can be controlled by an option. In case of standard numeric styles `autocite=superscript,` will yield the `\supercite` behaviour.

I recommend you use `\autocite` and configure its behaviour to your liking.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, autocite=superscript]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem^1]